# Connection reset by peer when uploadFileToBlockBlob in azure-storage-blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are using java lib azure-storage-blob 11.0.1 to upload png file with function uploadFileToBlockBlob.

Sometimes we got this error java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
It happens randomly.

stack:

> [java.lang.RuntimeException]: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by
>   peer 
>                                                                io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow() in
>   ExceptionHelper.java:45
>                                                     io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet() in
>   BlockingMultiObserver.java:91
>                                                                                       io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet() in Single.java:2656

We used the azure-storage-blob version 10.1.0 , and we were confused with the error

> "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException"

We tried to upgrade the version, and now we get this error.

```java
public String uploadFile(String blobName, File sourceFile) throws Exception {
    BlockBlobURL blobURL = containerURL.createBlockBlobURL(blobName);
    AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath());

        try {
            BlobHTTPHeaders headers = new BlobHTTPHeaders();
            headers.withBlobContentType("image/png");
            TransferManagerUploadToBlockBlobOptions options = new TransferManagerUploadToBlockBlobOptions(null, headers, null, null, null);

            CommonRestResponse response = TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blobURL, 8 * 1024 * 1024, null, options).blockingGet();
            return blobURL.toString();

        } finally {
            fileChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of `README.md` of Azure Storage SDK for Java on GitHub, as the figure below, `A stepping stone in our path to v12. We do not currently recommend adopting this.` said offical repo.

[image]

So I recommended to downgrade to [Storage SDK v8 for Java](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java/tree/legacy-master), not `v10` or up to `v12` which are all based on RxJava for asynchronization. `v8` is the latest stable version for synchronization methods.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```